# In Python, how do you return a list of indexes for an arbitarily nested element?

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming

Say I have a list:

```
>>> nested=[[1, 2], [3, [4]]]
```

I am trying to get a function that would return `[1,1,0]` if I were looking for `4`. If the specified element weren't in the list then it would return an empty list, `[]`.

`Nested` could have any structure, so I am thinking some type of recursive function would be best, but am having trouble controlling for depth and breadth of the structure.

This is *not* working code, but along the lines of what I am thinking:

```
def locate(x,element,loc=[0],counter=0):
    for c,i in enumerate(x):
        if isinstance(i,list):
            locate(i,loc+[0],counter+1)
        else:
            loc[counter]=c
            if i==element: return loc
```

The function call would look something like this:

```
>>> locate(nested,4)
[1,1,0]
```

A recursive function might not be the best solution, but just my attempt.

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? Other than not returning when you recurse. And using a default mutable argument.

Comment: ie `return locate(i,loc+[0],counter+1)`

Comment: What if there are multiple matches?

Comment: @AndrasDeak returning the first instance would be fine to keep functionality similar to the list index method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def nested_find(l, e):
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            t = nested_find(x, e)
            if t:
                return [i] + t
        elif x == e:
            return [i]
```

This returns `None` if `e` not in `l`

Comment: FYI, `(x, list);` has a semi-colon

Comment: Would you mind providing a bit more explanation on how this works?

Comment: @LMc Sure. This goes through every element of the list and if that element is itself a list, calls itself on that list.  If the element is equal to what we're looking for , we return a list containing its index in the most immediate list. Then, as we back out of the recursive calls, we add the index of the list that contained, at some level, what we are looking for. In cases where it doesn't find the target element in the list, it reaches the end without a return statement and thus returns `None`

Answer (score 6):

You might consider moving to some kind of tree data structure instead, but here's an example with your current data structure:

```
from collections import Iterable

def flatten(collection, depth=()):
    for i, element in enumerate(collection):
        if isinstance(element, Iterable) and not isinstance(element, str):
            yield from flatten(element, depth=depth + (i,))
        else:
            yield element, depth + (i,)

def locate(nested, element):
    for v, indices in flatten(nested):
        if v == element:
            return indices
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code returns None if the element is not found, otherwise returns the required output:

```
   def locate(lst,ele):
        return  _locate(lst,ele,[])

    def _locate(lst,ele,res):
        for i,x in enumerate(lst):
            if isinstance(x,list):
                retVal = locate(x,ele,res+[i])
                if retVal is not None:
                    return retVal
            elif x==ele:
                return res+[i]
        return None
```